# Unable to install Realm in build.gradle in android studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want to install Realm in android studio for a java project, and It hasnt being sucessfull.

I was expecting

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

But I got this.

This is the build.gradle(Project: NoteTaking)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
}
```

This is the build.gradle(Module: NoteTaking)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.notetaking'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.notetaking"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

}
```

THis is the settings.gradle (Project settings)

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "NoteTaking"
include ':app'
```

I have tried changing the Gradle JDK to 11, I am currntly on andriod studio default JDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to finally solve my problem.
Here is how I did it.

in the

> build.gradle(Project NoteTaking)

I replaced all code with

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.11.1"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

in the

> build.gradle(Module: NoteTaking.app)

I added

> id 'realm-android'

to plugins

and then apply

> apply plugin: "realm-android

immediatly after the plugins closing tag

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'realm-android'
}

apply plugin: "realm-android"
```

Comment: It works perfectly, Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you find it useful.